# This short-circuit (&&) should work but something isn't

Tags: java, android, functional-programming, logic

WHen both are true I want it to toast... but it's seeing them as false.

```
if (dateTime > System.currentTimeMillis() && chkBox.isChecked()){
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "BEFORE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     return;
    };
```

Comment: Your question is a bit cryptic... can you better explain yourself?

Comment: What ever your dateTime is if it is deduced programmatically it can never be greater than System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: @ingsaurabh, `long dateTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 24*60*60*1000L //Tomorrow` That's not true...

Comment: OP - You are making an extraordinary claim (that android's `&&` support is broken) ... without any evidence whatsoever.  Bzzzt.  There are many more likely explanations for this that your claim.

Comment: @st0le hahaha but still you have to add an extra day to it :P

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest printing out the values of:

```
dateTime
System.currentTimeMillis()
chkBox.isChecked()
```

before the `if` statement because I'm pretty certain that, short of a massive failure in your tool-chain (compiler and so forth), the `&&` works just fine in that statement. And also printing something inside the `if` statement before the `Toast` line.

Therefore I have to assume one of the following.

1. `dateTime` is *not* greater than `System.currentTimeMillis()` - for example, if `dateTime` is assigned from the current time at some point then it will always be less than or equal to the current time after that, clock modifications and bizarre cosmological interference from the presence of black holes notwithstanding :-)
2. `chkBox.isChecked()` is returning *false.*
3. The `if` *is* working okay but the `Toast` line is not doing anything obvious/visible.

The chances of a well used tool-chain like Java and/or the Android stuff being defective at such a basic operation are slim to none.